# Django DRF follow relationships

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, relationship

Well, I am trying to follow relationships with Django Rest Framework.

Here is a simplified model :

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Model2(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And Serializers :

```
class Model1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'

class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = '__all__'
```

From Model2, I would like to access owner properties, like email...

Without DRF and in a standard template, I would do this :

```
{{ instanceOfModel2.model1.owner.email }}
```

This would follow the relationship.

Do you have any idea how could I achieve this using Django DRF?

I looked at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/
But what I want is the opposite way... And I'd like to not expose the Django User model through a REST API....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define new fields along with the [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) attribute using dotted notation:

```
class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='model1.owner.email', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a User Serializer and relate the serializers with each other.

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class Model1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'

class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model1 = Model1Serializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the field to be `read only` :

`class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = ('email', ...)
    def get_email(self, obj):
        return obj.model1.owner.email`